# TeXstudio \cite-autocomplete stopped working

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

Today my autocomplete for my citations stopped.

I am using TeXstudio and already tried:

- adding `bibtex` to autocomplete in the options,
- selecting the folder containing the `bibtex` file (Options)
- Idefix--> Reconstruct structure.

But the problem still exists.

My current autocomplete looks like this

[image: http://i.imgur.com/XKKlEeP.png]

Comment: Do you still have this problem? How is your setup? Where are your citations stored? What have you changed before this stopped working?

Comment: Yeah the problem still exists. Sometimes it works again for one day and then vanishes again.
I also run Texstudio on my laptop with the exact same settings working on the same document, where the autocomplete works just fine. So I guess there is a flaw somewhere in the software.

Setup: Desktop: W7 64bit, Version 2.10.6
Laptop: W10 64bit, Version 2.10.6

Citations are stored as .bib in the same folder as the main tex document.

I changed nothing.

Comment: I just checked Help -> Check for active autocomplete lists and got an exception error. Here is the logfile:
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION at 5d1bde (TXS-Version 5771:be44b21f6401 R )
[bt] 0055e030  ??? error: 487
[bt] 005d1bde  ??? error: 487
[bt] 005e6393  ??? error: 487
[bt] 0079a818  ??? error: 487
[bt] 68a22ca2  ZN11QMetaObject8activateEP7QObjectiiPPv+1746

Comment: Ok, to be honest, that's too cryptic for me... Well, as you seem to have version 5771 and I am having 5804, I think we should start debugging by uninstalling and installing the most recent version. Do you have any custom stuff in your TXS. If not, please make sure to delete `%APPDATA%\texstudio\ ` before the new installation.

Comment: I will do next week. Most of my thesis is already done and my deadline is monday. So I don't have much time to debug right now :D

Comment: I have the same issue on Ubuntu 18.04. It stopped working suddenly. Have you found a solution for this?